# Dynamically generate an object's HTML with Razor

Tags: c#, html, razor, content-negotiation

I'd like to create a `MediaTypeFormatter` that handles HTML MIME types, similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11783866/1680677). The catch is that I don't want (or have) a view/template file: I want to generate the HTML string *given just the object (the value) and it's type*.

- If Razor already supports this, please point me to the documentation or an example.
- If Razor covers only a part of my need, please help me understand the gap that I'd need to fill in.
- If Razor isn't helpful, I assume reflection is my best bet. If you want to start me off, be my guest.

I feel like I've seen something similar to what I need, but I can't find it at this point. **What functionality does Razor have to support my use case?**

Comment: I'm confused. You don't want to have a view/template but you want to use Razor, which is a templating language?

Comment: @DavidG I want a view minus the file. Does that make sense?